# Como remover linhas duplicadas mantendo outras colunas

Tags: sql, oracle

No exemplo abaixo, estou interessado em remover duplicações das linhas nas colunas `title` e `time` sem me importar com as demais colunas.

No exemplo abaixo estou interessado que a consulta retorne as linhas 32, 34 e 36 e todas as colunas.

```
id | title   | time  | domain
32   title1    12:30   domain1.com
33   title1    12:30   domain2.com
34   title2    14:20   domain1.com
35   title2    14:20   domain2.com
36   title3    15:30   domain55.com
```

Comment: Seria possivel, postar como esta tentando fazer? e as tabelas? é apenas uma tabela? explique melhor o seu problema.

Comment: @GOKUSSJGod Problema resolvido, muito obrigado!

Comment: @GOKUSSJGod Oracle

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza  novamente, a tag adicionada é irrelevante pra pergunta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User o [Group by](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) e o [min()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms179916.aspx),

```
declare @tabela table
(
   id int,
   title varchar(20),
   time time,
   domain varchar(30)
)

insert into @tabela values

(32, 'title1',    '12:30' ,  'domain65.com'),
(33, 'title1',    '12:30' ,  'domain2.com'),
(34, 'title2',    '14:20' ,  'domain1.com'),
(35, 'title2',    '14:20' ,  'domain2.com'),
(36, 'title3',    '15:30' ,  'domain55.com')

select min(id) as ID, title, time, (select domain from @tabela where id = min(t1.id)) 
from @tabela t1
group by title, time
```

Ou

```
select min(id) as ID, title, time, min(domain) from @tabela
group by title, time
```

Comment: Poderia explicar no seu código como isso funciona? Eu tenho interesse na pergunta, mas sua resposta apresenta apenas os códigos, não sei o que eles estão fazendo.

Comment: @Florida, A parte que realmente importa para pergunta é o select... praticamente estou agrupando os campos title, time, ou seja todo que for igual nesses campos serão agrupados em uma unica linha. já o MIN() como o nome já é intuitivo pega o minimo valor das linhas que são agrupadas no group by. Nada de complicado, por isso não expliquei aqui. as referencias podem ajudar nessa parte.